# How to update a field in array of object Nodejs/MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

All I want is to update the value of the field "done" to "true"

I m developping with nodejs

here is the document :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a730e55114dbc2a0455c630"),
"email" : "email@gmail.com",
"password" : "12356789",
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "new to do ",
        "description" : "new something ",
        "date" : "2018-02-07T18:16:29.469Z",
        "done" : false
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "new to d odo ",
        "description" : "dod ododoododododo",
        "date" : "2018-02-07T18:25:14.881Z",
        "done" : false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You want to update it for some specific element or for each element in array?

Comment: a specific element for example the second one with the title  "new to d odo "
I want to change done to "true"

Comment: You could try using the `$set` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: can you tell a little bit more ?  you want to change an object in nodejs , or  in mongodb ?

Comment: I'm Sorry that the question wasn't clear for you !

I want to update the field "done" in the task named "new to d odo " in the array "tasks" in the hole object with nodeJS I'm asking for the querry because this document is from a MongoDb Database.

Comment: _____  
  You could try using the $set operator: 
    docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set – t3__rry 7 
    hours ago
_____

I couldn't find how to acces into the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
db.collectionName.update({
     "tasks.title": "new to d odo "
}, {
    $set: { "tasks.$.done": true }
})
```

You can check more details [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`$push`

`$set`

`$addToSet`

you can use these operators to insert any object or any value to an array in the mongoose model.